# I want bring my desktop pc to the US, will the customs pass it?

Tags: usa, malaysia

I'm traveling to the US from Malaysia and I will be bringing my computer desktop and monitor. Will I face any issues with US customs?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you will not have any problems.

However please note that software piracy is a serious offense in the US and if you are suspected of carrying pirated software, your hard drive may be confiscated.

Please make sure you place your desktop and monitor in your checked-in luggage; because if you bring it with you in your carry-on - according to new rules, you'll be asked to turn it on at the security checkpoint. If you cannot turn it on, it will be confiscated.

Comment: The "turn it on" rules apply to things like laptops, tablets, phones, etc.  I doubt they would confiscate a desktop, since it is easily inspected for explosives by removing the side panels.  I carried a desktop on board earlier this year without incident, as there is no way I was checking it and risking someone stealing it and the data on the hard drive.

Comment: If you are carrying a traditional desktop "tower" then yes, but if you are carrying a compact desktop computer - like a mac mini or one of those small alienware boxes, then you have the same restrictions as the laptop.